# The mysterious Cloud Datastore entries and keeps growing

Tags: google-app-engine, datastore

My project is just a WordPress installation deployed to Google App Engine Standard Environment.

According to the [list of features](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/about-the-standard-environment#datastore), Datastore is not available for PHP, however I can see some Cloud Datastore entries in the Resources card on the project's App Engine dashboard, [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjxJr.png) and its' amount grows little by little.

Cloud Datastore dashboard shows me that I have no datastore entries.

I know, I could disable writes to datastore from the Google Cloud Console or even completely deactivate Cloud Datastore API for the project — what I definitely would do if it keeps growing — but I want to understand the causes of these datastore entries and maybe its contents if possible.

Comment: Have you tried a support ticket?

Comment: @ceejayoz, no I'm my support level is Bronze, so I have only billing support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Datastore Entity console](https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities/) to see the different Entity Kinds that are being saved to your project. Other Google Cloud products that you are using may also use the Datastore to save information; not just your App Engine app via the Datastore API.

If you see Kinds with names beginning with '_AE' or '_GAE' these denote project-level metadata that are being saved. If you do not see any Datastore Kinds, I ask that you open an [Issue Report](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry) with your project ID so that we can investigate deeper.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13459

Comment: Following the public issue, the entities you described were `__BlobInfo__` metadata entities created to track objects in Google Cloud Storage, accessible via the Blobstore API.  You are not billed for these entities.